# Android JodaTime convert UTC to User's time

Tags: java, android

I am stuck while solving this naive scenario. Here is what I designed to convert UTC to local time.

```
public static DateTime timezoneAwareDate(Date date){
    DateTime input = new DateTime(date,DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime output = input.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    Log.d(niftyFunctions.LOG_TAG,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mmm-dd hh:mm").format(output.toDate()));
    return output;
}
```

Here is what my input date looks like in UTC, coming from server:

```
2015-07-28 16:30
```

But here is what I am getting on my phone which is in IST from Log.d statement:

```
2015-030-28 07:30
```

I am going crazy about what's actually happening. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went with Joda-less solution using just the native libs. Here is the function

```
/**
     * Returns localtime for UTC
     *
     * @param date
     * @return
     */
    public static Date timezoneAwareDate(String date){
        // create simpledateformat for UTC dates in database
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Date output;
        // parse time
        try{
            output = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        }catch (Exception e){
            // return current time
            output = new Date();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: But how to do it with Joda? I want to use the force of Joda!